# Porque To_char(3E4) não resulta em '3E4'?

Tags: sql, oracle, conversão-de-tipo

Galera como eu converto um número exponencial (NUMBER) para string (VARCHAR) mas que fique expresso igual??

Exemplo:

```
SQL> SELECT   TO_CHAR (NUMERO) NUMCONVERT
  2    FROM   (SELECT   3E4 NUMERO FROM DUAL);

NUMCONVERT
----------------------------------------
30000
```

Como retornar '3E4'??

Answer (score 1):

Tenta dessa forma:

`TO_CHAR(number, '9.9EEEE')`

**Fonte:** http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Comment: Tentei também usar dessa forma porém depois que é convertido fica   '3.0E+04' 
Eu precisava de '3E4' expresso igual ao numero inteiro.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando somente o `TO_CHAR(numero,'FM9.9EEEE')`, retorna:

> 3.E+04

Mas como você quer que fique do mesmo jeito, fiz uma *Gambiarra*:

```
   SELECT REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
                REPLACE(TO_CHAR(numero,'FM9.9EEEE'),
                'E+0','e')
             ,'E+','e')
           ,'.','') numconvert
      FROM (SELECT 3e4 as numero
              FROM dual);
```

Retornando:

> 3e4

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Até daria David, o problema é que não é especificamente 3E4. Terá valores como: 1E-1, 1.67E-1, 1.99E1....

Comment: A outra reposta te ajudara melhor, senão vamos ter um monte de `REPLACE`